# Cuál es el error al compilar este package

Tags: oracle-11g

tengo creado un trigger el cual me da error de mutación, investigué uno de los métodos(https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions#solution_1) para solucionar dicho problema el cual es crea una tabla temporal, al seguir la sintaxis de la página trato de correrlo, pero me da este error, y no sé en realidad qué es.

```
Error(51,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored    
Error(52,23): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Mis tablas:

```
create table PELICULA 
(
ID_PELICULA varchar(10),
NOMBRE_PELICULA varchar(40),
ANIO_PELICULA int,
DURACION_PELICULA_MINUTOS int,
TOTAL_ACTORES int,
LUGAR_FILMACION varchar(40),
TOTAL_HOMBRES_PELICULA int,
TOTAL_MUJERES_PELICULA int,
constraint PK_ELENCO_PELICULA primary key (ID_PELICULA)
);

insert into ACTOR (ID_ACTOR, GENERO_ACTOR)values ('1','asdasdasd');
insert into ACTOR (ID_ACTOR, GENERO_ACTOR)values ('12','MASCULINO');
insert into PELICULA (ID_PELICULA, ANIO_PELICULA)values ('13',1995);
select * from PELICULA;
drop trigger pelicula;

create table ACTOR
(
ID_ACTOR varchar(10),
NOMBRE_ACTOR varchar(40),
GENERO_ACTOR varchar(20),
ANIO_NACIMIENTO int,
TOTAL_PELICULAS_FILMADAS int,
constraint PK_ELENCO_ACTOR primary key (ID_ACTOR)
);

create table ELENCO
(
IDPELICULA varchar(10),
IDACTOR varchar(10),
EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA int,
PAGOALACTOR_PORLAPELICULA number(6,2),
constraint FK_ELENCO_PELICULA foreign key (IDPELICULA) references PELICULA 
(ID_PELICULA),
constraint FK_ELENCO_ACTOR foreign key (IDACTOR) references ACTOR (ID_ACTOR)
);
create global temporary table PELICULA_MODS (
EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOP int
) on commit delete rows;
DROP TABLE PELICULA_MODS;
```

Mi package:

```
CREATE PACKAGE PELICULA_API AS 
   PROCEDURE PELICULA_RCHANGE(P_EDADACTOR 
ELENCO.EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA%TYPE); 
END PELICULA_API; 

 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PELICULA_API AS
PROCEDURE PELICULA_RCHANGE (P_EDADACTOR  IN  
ELENCO.EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA%TYPE)IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO PELICULA_MODS (EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOP)VALUES (P_EDADACTOR);
 END PELICULA_RCHANGE;
PROCEDURE PELICULA_SCHANGE IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ELENCO (IDPELICULA, IDACTOR, EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA, 
PAGOALACTOR_PORLAPELICULA)
    VALUES ('22','12',EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOP, 4512.24);
  DELETE FROM PELICULA_MODS;
END PELICULA_SCHANGE;
END PELICULA_API;
```

Comment: Veo el problema.. EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOP es un nombre de columna adentro de un insert.. no falta algo ahi?

Comment: pues no sé a que te refieres, EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOP  en el insert es para declarar el insertar solo ese valor en la tabla PELICULA_MODS...

Comment: en el segundo insert, esta dentro de values..

Comment: Ya intenté sacar la columna pero me da el mismo error, la verdad no entiendo, no sé que debería poner o cambiar.

Comment: y si probas proceso por proceso, a ver cual de todos esta fallando.. contruis el package de a uno.. hasta que descubras cual esta mal... sobre el aire es mas dificil ayudarte..

Answer (score 0):

Veo varios errores en tu código.

Empezando por la forma en como estás declarando tu paquete. El Stored Procedure *PELICULA_SCHANGE* no está declarado en tu Encabezado. La forma correcta es la siguiente.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PELICULA_API
AS
    PROCEDURE PELICULA_RCHANGE(P_EDADACTOR ELENCO.EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA%TYPE);
    PROCEDURE PELICULA_SCHANGE(P_EDADACTOR ELENCO.EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA%TYPE);
END PELICULA_APIA;
/
```

Por otro lado, en el Stored Procedure **PELICULA_SCHANGE** intentas insertar en el campo *EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA* de la tabla *ELENCO*; el campo EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOP de la tabla PELICULA_MODS. Siendo que esto no puede ser posible.

En todo caso, el valor correcto a insertar sería el parámetro de entrada de tu Stored Procedure **PELICULA_SCHANGE**.

Te recomiendo ordenar tu código para que este sea más legible; así como abreviar los nombres de tus columnas. El siguiente código compila sin problema alguno y debes de adaptarlo según el objetivo final del Stored Procedure.

Por cierto, ¿Es realmente necesario hacer uso de una tabla temporal? Bien podrías hacer uso de una tabla Transaccional común.

¡Saludos!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PELICULA_API 
AS
    PROCEDURE PELICULA_RCHANGE(P_EDADACTOR ELENCO.EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA%TYPE);
    PROCEDURE PELICULA_SCHANGE(P_EDADACTOR ELENCO.EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA%TYPE);
END PELICULA_API; 
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PELICULA_API
AS
    PROCEDURE PELICULA_RCHANGE (P_EDADACTOR  IN  ELENCO.EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA%TYPE)
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PELICULA_MODS(EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOP)VALUES(P_EDADACTOR);
    END PELICULA_RCHANGE;

    PROCEDURE PELICULA_SCHANGE(P_EDADACTOR IN ELENCO.EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA%TYPE) 
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ELENCO(IDPELICULA, 
                           IDACTOR, 
                           EDADACTOR_CUANDOFILMOPELICULA, 
                           PAGOALACTOR_PORLAPELICULA)
                    VALUES ('22',
                            '12',
                            P_EDADACTOR, 
                            4512.24);
         DELETE FROM PELICULA_MODS;
    END PELICULA_SCHANGE;
END PELICULA_API;
```